# Como botar valor no select

Tags: php

Meu select está assim:

```
Nome do carro:<br>
<input type="text" name="nomeCarro" value="<?php echo $dados['nome']; ?>"><br>
Marca:<br>
<select name="marcas">
  <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="Bmw">Bmw</option>
  <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
</select>

Ano:<br>
<input type="numeric" name="ano" value="<?php echo $dados['ano']; ?>"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
```

A dúvida é: Como faço para trazer o valor do select, já que trouxe dos outros também.

[image: Só aparece 'Toyota' no select, mesmo sendo outra marca]

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que não está a funcionar?

Comment: e como trouxe dos outros?

Answer (score 0):

Suponhamos que você deve ter uma tabela justamente para **alocar os valores das marcas.**

Acredito que você já use *tabelas relacionadas*. Então você deve ter salvo apenas o ID da marca na tabela de onde você está buscando esses valores, sendo assim você deverá criar um método para retornar o nome de acordo com o ID.

[]s.

```
<select name='marcas'>
   <?php
       foreach($dados['marcas'] as $value)
       {
          echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.Retornar::nomeMarca($value).'</option>;
       }
   ?>
</select>
```